# RESTful composition/inclusion of other resources

Tags: design-patterns, rest, http

I have a few HTTP resources, and i'm wondering if including the models of one in the other is acceptable or if there is a cleaner method.

In this example, we have a ton of "news" resources, and users can subscribe via a resource called "subscription":

```
==>/news-items/{id}/
{
    "id": 987,
    "url": "http://example.com/foo/bar",
    "title": "Wow! A Headline",
}
```

And

```
==> /users/{user-id}/subscriptions/
[
    {
         "id" : 123
         "keywords": "Mr Celebrity"
    },
    ...
]
```

And then the endpoint that includes the models of both resources ...

```
==> /users/{user-id}/my-news/
[
    {
        "id": 987,
        "url": "http://example.com/foo/bar",
        "title": "Wow! A Headline",
        "matched_by": [
            {
                "id": 123,
                "keywords": "Wow",
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

The usecase is fairly self explanatory for this: A feed of news with 'matched by "Mr Celebrity"' next to it. It feels a bit weird to have an endpoint that consists only of nested/composite models from other endpoints ... Is this acceptable practice or problematic?

The endpoint will be read-only, and the other options seem to be:

1. HATEOAS-style: "matched_by" and the news item are URLs pointing to a news item and subscription. Would require more HTTP requests.
2. Some kind of multi-payload response with a HATEOAS primary payload then 'related' payload of the referenced resources. Not seen this done before.
3. ??? some other options?

If my approach is sound, great, but I want to hear what others would do if there is a better alternative.

Thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't the `/users/{user-id}/subscriptions/` be a collection? In your example it obviously isn't one. And what exactly would be contained in the `"matched_by"` collection? Currently my recommendation would be `option 1.` with resource expansion functionality. Kinda like described [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/linking-and-resource-expansion-rest-api-tips/).

Comment: @teresko yes you are right re, the collection. Edited the question. Your link seems to describe a good option in expansion. "matched_by" is a set of subscription resources that "matched" the news item (therefore putting it in the user's feed).

Comment: Also, part of being uneasy is the "matched_by" attribute only existing in the latter resource and not the canonical resource, so I was considering a "matched_by":[] in the first resource for the news item for completeness even though it will never contain anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A feed of news with 'matched by "Mr Celebrity"' next to it. It feels a
>   bit weird to have an endpoint that consists only of nested/composite
>   models from other endpoints ... Is this acceptable practice or
>   problematic?

Having embedded resource representations is perfectly valid, since you describe a resource graph in where every resource can be connected to another resources...

If I were you I'd check some standard hypermedia type instead of creating an own. For example: [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/), [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), [Collection+JSON](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/), [etc...](http://sookocheff.com/posts/2014-03-11-on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/)

> HATEOAS-style: "matched_by" and the news item are URLs pointing to a
>   news item and subscription. Would require more HTTP requests.

HATEOAS is about using hyperlinks, not plain URLs. Don't confuse these terms... A hyperlink consists of at least a HTTP method (`calling an operation`) and an URL (`on a resource`). By REST you have to add some meta-data to it, for example [link relation](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) or [Hydra:Operation](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/) (if you prefer RDF).

Just a copy-paste HAL example from one of the linked sites:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": { "href": "https://api.example.com/player/1234567890/friends" },
        "next": { "href": "https://api.example.com/player/1234567890/friends?page=2" }
    },
    "size": "2",
    "_embedded": { 
        "player": [
            { 
                "_links": { 
                    "self": { "href": "https://api.example.com/player/1895638109" },
                    "friends": { "href": "https://api.example.com/player/1895638109/friends" }
                },
                "playerId": "1895638109",
                "name": "Sheldon Dong",
                "alternateName": "sdong",
                "image": "https://api.example.com/player/1895638109/avatar.png"
            },
            { 
                "_links": { 
                    "self": { "href": "https://api.example.com/player/8371023509" },
                    "friends": { "href": "https://api.example.com/player/8371023509/friends" }
                },
                "playerId": "8371023509",
                "name": "Martin Liu",
                "alternateName": "mliu",
                "image": "https://api.example.com/player/8371023509/avatar.png"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see this defines one `size` property and two embedded `player`s for a collection resource. Every representation contains links. You can find the main resource identifier (URI) under the links having `self` link relation. This is just one example. Most of the generic hypermedia types use similar approaches. Btw. this is just the GET part of the story. (HAL does not support POST, PUT, DELETE links, you have to use an extension to describe them.)

Understanding a better solution, like [RDF](http://www.w3.org/RDF/) with [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/) and [Hydra](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/) would be a longer story...

Comment: Really enjoyed reading this, consider the questions answered. Thank you for taking the time to answer. RDF is lovely, so I might look in to JSON-LD. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Just to mention the Hydra vocab (for REST APIs) is not a standard yet. The [Hydra group](http://www.w3.org/community/hydra/) is currently working on it. If you have any questions or suggestions you can join to the group and write to the public-hydra mailing list...

Comment: You might be interested in the [dissertation of Markus](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/research/third-generation-web-apis-bridging-the-gap-between-rest-and-linked-data.pdf), it is about how they standardized JSON-LD and created the Hydra vocab. (I am on the 93/214 page now, hard stuff.) I guess you already know the [Fielding dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).